# How to set airflow DAG runs continuously

Tags: python, airflow

I am using airflow to schedule a spark job, I need to got a DAG "run continuously" -- Like I just want a DAG to run, and when it finishes, to start a new DAG instance again.

I have two options in my mind:
1. Allow only one DAG instance running at a time and run the DAG more frequently
2. Have another DAG to watch and kick off when it is needed.

Have anyone implement it? Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: please give reason for downvote

Answer (score 1):

[Schedule a continually airflow DAG run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959095/schedule-a-continually-airflow-dag-run)

> You should be able to use the TriggerDagRunOperator to rerun the DAG after the last task is finished.