# Schedule a continually airflow DAG run

Tags: airflow

Is there a way to run airflow DAG in a loop? 
When trying to create a cycle (connecting the last component to the upstream of the last one) I got "Cycle detected in DAG. Faulty task: ..."
Generally, I have a short flow of 3 BashOperator components which i want to run continually (without any input-output pass from the last component to the first).
Thanks!

Comment: You're aware DAG means _Directed Acyclic Graph_ right ? What's your UseCase ? Maybe Airflow is not the right tool for this task

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use the TriggerDagRunOperator to rerun the DAG after the last task is finished. Just put it after the last operator and make it trigger the same DAG.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `@continuous` cron preset in the airflow version 2.7.3